# "Invalid theme" using Gnome 3 themes

Tags: gnome, themes

I am trying to change the shell theme on my acer C7 chromebook laptop. I put ubuntu on the laptop with chrubuntu. I don't know if this has anything to do with the problems I'm running into, but I just figured I'd put it out there.

I use Gnome, and I already have the Tweak Tool. I *think* I have the shell-user-theme extension, though I have encountered various errors while trying to download it in various ways. I'm relatively new to using the terminal. When I go to Theme in Tweak Tool, I have the option of opening a theme, but when I try to open a downloaded theme it briefly flashes "invalid theme". I'm trying to install the Soothe theme (I just want to successfully install any theme at all for starters.) I tried a different theme, Legacy, but it didn't show up at all when I went to open it in the tweak tool.

Am I doing something wrong? Can I fix this? Has anyone else had this problem too?

UPDATE: [This](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-gnome-shell-themes-ubuntu-12-04) tutorial says at the end that there should be a .themes folder under my home folder, however, there isn't. I tried making a folder and calling it .themes but the folder itself doesn't show up in tweak tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, make sure you're using the right themes (for Gnome 3.8 I would presume).

Second, you need to put the theme folder (not the zip, but the contents of the zip), into /usr/share/themes.

Hope this helps!